# How to search the web with Google Search API without limit

Tags: c#, google-api, google-search-api

I need a web search be my app and it would be fine to use google web search for.
This works in different cases when I do the code by myself or use assemblies like GAPI.
The problem is that I ever get an error because of paging the results:

> ResponseStatus: 400, Reason: out of range start

About this problem I found this by the GAPI developer:
Google AJAX Search API does not allow more than 64 results (e.g. max page is 56).

But I need more results as this is to less for my usage I need at least 500...
Is there another way to get more result by searching the web?

Comment: Can you post your code that is not working please?  I assume your code fails but the third party code works?

Comment: I tried out code I found also in the net like this: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2165-how-to-search-google-and-bing-in-c/ - when I look behind the GAPI the function is similar and the trouble the same ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like GAPI is using the old Google Search API which has been officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010.

If you want more results you should look into another library or implementing your own using the Google Custom Search API:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure about is really the new version. I think this is just for a custom page search isn't it? Please have a look at the cx parameter. But I need to search the google result and no custom page - or do I missunderstand?

Comment: You need to read more about the API, you're using a limited deprecated version that isn't supported anymore, this is the API Google refers users of the old API. You can use it to do a regular Google search.

Comment: I read the article and the docs it point to but I'm sorry I found nothing about a WebSearch. When yopu choose "Getting started" you'll see what is need for basic use at point 2b. Set up a custom search engine . So maybe I'm wrong and there's a sample available to use this without custom search engine?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, but you need to do some more reading. 2 minutes on the page I found:
Links to a .NET API (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Downloads)
Examples on the CustomSearch API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest)

There's no simple plug and play solution, you will have to do some work here.